# Can not make css binding to work in knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to make a simple example with css binding in knockout. After reading [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html), I thought that [this will yield correct result](http://jsfiddle.net/f6BCT/1/).

Basically I have a simple model:

```
function ArticlesViewModel(){
    this.popularTags = [{
        id: 1,
        s: ko.observable(false)
    },{
        id: 2,
        s: ko.observable(false)
    },{
        id: 2,
        s: ko.observable(true)
    }];
}

ko.applyBindings(new ArticlesViewModel());
```

And I want to add a particular class based on the the s property. So I tried the following view but with no result:

```
<span data-bind="foreach: popularTags">
    <span class="square" data-bind="text: id, css: { selected: s == false}"></span>
</span>
```

Can someone enlighten what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to unwrap the observable `selected: s() == false`: http://jsfiddle.net/f6BCT/2/

```
<span class="square" data-bind="text: id, css: { selected: s() == false}"></span>
```